# Creating OpenGl Window with c++ in windows using 64 bit + Custom Window Shape (etc smooth corners not rectangular)

Tags: c++, opengl, 64-bit

Im trying to make a software in c++ using OpenGl & C++ it must be 64 bit and be able to have custom window (frame/"handler") etc no normal windows rectangle around it... and use an opacity on etc corners... so get rounded corners on the window/frame.. Anyone know what libs and how to do this? I know OpenGl & C++ however im not sure how to get the window & 64 bit.. since i tried glut but it fails on the 64 bit version and also do not feature the custom framing that i want... Any advice appreciated (: (I want to not use any extra libs) so creating a opengl context myself and import the opengl32.dll and functions from "windows" rather then using libs like etc glut :3 )

Comment: FreeGLUT should have a 64-bit version and is compatible with GLUT.

Comment: However i would like to NOT use glut since it does not support the features i want :/ I want my window to have no standard windows frame.. and be able to use opacity in the window (:

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to take a closer look to the winapi (MS Windows only).
The procedure of creating a window is pretty straight forward and "binding" OpenGL to it is not that difficult. There is even a nice tutorial from the khronos-group:

[OpenGL Winapi Setup Tutorial](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Creating_an_OpenGL_Context_(WGL))

Thats the first step, creating round edges is another.
There are tons of approaches to achieve the desired effect, I assume you want to make your window frame as rounded in the default window 7 scheme.

[Enabling Visual Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649781(v=vs.85).aspx)

If that is not what you want, you can create a frame by yourself by opening a frameless window with winapi and draw your frame with OpenGL.

Comment: My problem is how to Render the frame with OpenGl.. etc Create Context :/

Comment: Creating the context for rendering is described pretty well in the first link. Do you have any experience using OpenGL or are you a newcomer ?

Comment: I have experience using Gl but never setting or creating the context.. and i would like an example for create+set a context in c# (since before i have used Glut and OpenTk) Tnx

Comment: You happen to know how to create OpenGl Context and use/bind to a emty windows form window?